# Django online university development

Tags: javascript, django, asynchronous, media

**Intro**
I'm trying to build an online university system using Django 1.5 and python 2.7.

I've for the most pieced together my models with classes for:
Company -     students connected to a company
Course -      courses 1to1 with timeline and m2m with student through course_data
Student -     student foreign key with User to extend User functionality
Course_Data - holds unique user information for each course
Timeline -    holds references, ordering, and other attributes for the course timeline.
              The timeline references instances of each media type
and media classes for video,slide,essay, question, and whatever else.

**Question**
I'm trying to figure out how to dynamically display the timeline information to the user with an incremental list of what's coming up on a checksheet.  I'm also trying to have the slides change from one media type to another as the user progresses through the course.  I'm thinking I may need to do something in terms of async(javascript?) however I only have a vague idea of what I might need.  Any recommendations would be intensely appreciated.

**My knowledge**
I have an understanding of html5 + canvas, and css3.  I began learning python and django a month ago.  Python in a week(easy, and I love it) Django the next week.  I understand the fundamentals of Models, views, templates, static files, and implementing Django on a production server(was a pain).  I can make use of javascript and php if needbe however I would like to avoid that where possible.

**Extra Data** I'm using Zurb Foundation 4 for the baseline for my styling.  I love Foundation and haven't seen any problems yet with Django.  Pretty straightforward implementation with calls to the CSS and JS in a separate header/footer file.

Comment: While this looks like a thought out and well written question this really isn't the right type of question for StackOverflow.

Comment: Gotchya, I'll try either piecing together individual more direct technical situations or going somewhere else.

Comment: you can use jquery pluging by providing json data from the django server. Give it a shot

Comment: Looking into Dojango Django+dojo

Comment: update for anyone searching for this.  Dajax + backbone.js are awesome